# Odd attribute behavior

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a curious situation with attributes. I'm working with xUnit's InlineData attribute which takes a params of objects (params object[]). If I feed it an array and a string, all seems well:

```
[InlineData(new string[] { "Yada", "Yada yada" }, "Yada yada yada")]
```

... but if I feed it just an array:

```
[InlineData(new string[] { "Yada", "Yada yada" })]
```

... then I get this [error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0182?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0182)):

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
> or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

What could the issue be?

Comment: not really an answer to why, but it's `params` so you should just be passing `[InlineData("Yada", "Yada yada" )]`.

Comment: I've never seen this behavior, it seems odd, but sure enough I can reproduce it in .NET 5 and .NET Framework.

Comment: @Jamiec Not necessarily. If one of the arguments to the test method requires a string array then absolutely do they want to pass a string array. I just find it odd that it's accepted in one case and not in the other. I have tested the attribute as well and it actually gets the string array just fine.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes of course, that was a flippant comment. I meant in the case of you wanting to pass 2 simple strings, you dont need to pass an array of string as its `params`

Comment: I don't have a good explanation of why this happens, but if you want to be able to pass a string array as one element of the object array you can work around the syntax limitation with this: `[InlineData(new object[] { new string[] { "Yada", "Yada yada" } })]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll highlight the important bit of the error message

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression **of an attribute parameter type**

The parameter type is `object[]` so you can't pass it `string[]`.

In the first example you're implicitly passing an array of objects, one being a string array the other being a string... in the first example you're  effectively doing this:

```
[InlineData(new object[]{new string[] { "Yada", "Yada yada" }, "Yada yada yada"})]
```

In the second example, you *could* have done this

```
[InlineData(new object[] { "Yada", "Yada yada" })]
```

Comment: So this is a quirk of the attribute syntax, since you can't even force the attribute to match the string array as one element of its object array by casting, with `InlineData((object)new string[] { ... })`.

Comment: And if you were to use `new object[]` instead, it would be matched as the array parameter, and not one element of the array. Basically, it seems you're allowed to pass a string array as one element of the attribute object array if you also pass other elements, but not if it's the only element. Again, I find this behavior odd.

Comment: Thanks so much @Jamiec. This explains the observation very clearly.